# Can someone please tell me why this python decorator is not working?

Tags: python, list, decorator, python-decorators

```
def decoratorrt(func):
    def innerht():
        print("hello there")
        func()
        print("it has ended")
        return innerht

@decoratorrt
def hellot():
    print("hello","are you in")

hellot()
```

The error message that i am getting is TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 hellot()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Your decorator didn't return anything.  The `return innerht` line should probably not be indented that far.

Answer (score 3):

You overindented the `return innerht`; that should be the return from `decoratorrt`, but without it, `decoratorrt` is returning `None` implicitly (while `innerht` is trying to return itself). Fixed function:

```
def decoratorrt(func):
    def innerht():
        print("hello there")
        func()
        print("it has ended")
    return innerht  # Dedented
```